# How to create multiple class attribute with a for loop?

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, attributes

I need to create 16 identical `forms.Charfield` in a `Django` `form`. So, basically I need something like this:

```
Class MyClass(forms.Form):
   a_1 = forms.CharField()
   ....
   a_16 = forms.CharField()
```

Is there a way to create them in a `for` loop so I do not have to type the same thing 16 times?

I have tried:

```
Class MyClass(forms.Form):
    for i in range(1, 17):
        i = forms.CharField(
            label      = str(i),
            required   = False,
            max_length = 100,
        )
```

but this only creates one field because of course i is not expanded into 0, 1, 2 ... 16

I also tried to use `setattr` outside the class and to store the `forms.CharField` objects in a `list` but these did not work either. No field is shown in the rendered page.

```
Class MyClass(forms.Form):
    b = forms.CharField()

for i in range(1, 17):
    setattr(
        MyClass, 
        'qt_'+str(i), 
        forms.CharField(
            label      = 'Other TMT labeling',
            required   = False,
            widget     = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4,}),
        )
    )

Class MyClass(forms.Form):
    l = []
    for i in range(1, 17):
        l.append(forms.CharField(
            label      = str(i),
            required   = False,
            max_length = 100,
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this by overriding the `__init__` method of the Form Class:

```
Class MyClass(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       number_of_field_list = kwargs.pop('number_of_field_list')
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       for i in number_of_field_list:
          self.fields['q_{}'.format(i)] = forms.CharField(label=str(i), required=False, max_length=100)

# in view

def your_view(request):
   form = MyClass(number_of_field_list=[1,2,3,4,7])  # or use range(1,4)
   return render(request, 'template.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Yes, this is one way to do this that works. Is there a way to make the first thing I tried to work? How do I manage to expand i into 1,2,3,4 and assign the forms.Charfield to it?

Comment: I don't think you first implementation will work. For your second question, please see the updated answer.